# В IE9 скачет правый блок.

Tags: html, css

Во всех браузерах отображается норм, только в IE7 и в IE9 правый блок стоит секунд 5 и вниз уходит, как будто места не хватает. у блока свойство float: left.

квартирыелабуги.рф

div с id right

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что DIV растягивается по горизонтали на всю возможную ширину, несмотря на свойство float: left;
Задал фиксированную ширину, все заработало.